# fetch() in js (react hooks) - can I access data in third then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch, react-hooks

I'm practicing react and fetch api and I want to send some data but it does not work... Code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3003/users', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, password }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
          }
          throw new Error('Error');
        })
        .then(user => {
          setUser([...users, user]);
          console.log(user.id);
          setLoggedUserID(user.id);
        })
        .then(setLoggedUserID(13)) // Check added user's ID
        .then(errorUserChange(false)); // Change state and go to /loggedin page
```

In second then I receive user with name, password and id. When I console.log it, I can see proper id, but when I'm trying to send it with setLoggedUserID function to the state, I receive null. This function works fine in the next then (third), but over there I don't have access to data (above I've hardcoded 13). Whole fetch is in function called after form submission.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try making requests inside try-catch blocks. Also If you encounter something wrong use .then(...).catch(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3003/users', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ name, password }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });

const user = await res.json();

setUser(prev => [...prev, user]);

setLoggedUserID(user.id); // [loggedUserId, setLoggedUserID] = useState(null)
```

//

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedUserId) errorUserChange(false);
}, [loggedUserId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a **function** to `then()`.

You are trying to call `setLoggedUserID(13)` and pass its **return value** as the callback function.

Comment: also need to **return** something from previous .then if you want to access it in later .thens

Comment: I'm trying and still does not work :/ could you please tell me how to write it? I know that's not the best practice to learn... but I give up :/

Comment: .then(user => {
          setUser([...users, user]);
          console.log(user.id);
          ID = user.id;
          console.log(ID);
          return ID;
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log(ID);
          setLoggedUserID(ID);
        }) // Check added user's ID
        .then(errorUserChange(false)); now my code looks like that (ID defined above) and still nothing :/ of course console.log logs ID but function does not work